# How to identify and unselect only one character of column having enum datatype?

Tags: mysql, enums

I created a procedure where in I had the value of column with enum datatype asCompleteness_Type` ENUM('B', 'I', 'C', 'BC', 'BI', 'IC', 'BIC')

I wrote a procedure where I would like to display all the video game records which does not have 'I' in completeness_type column. Below is the proceudre I have written

```
    USE `videogame_collection_3`;
    DROP procedure IF EXISTS `Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something`;

      DELIMITER $$
                  USE `videogame_collection_3`$$
                 create PROCEDURE `Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something`(IN  Completenessip     VARCHAR(15))
                BEGIN
                 SELECT 
                   video_game.Game_Name,
               video_game.Genre,
              mycollection.Purchase_Date,
               mycollection.Purchase_Price,
                   mycollection.`Condition`,
                     platform.Platform_Name,
                    mycollection.Completeness_Type
                     FROM
                  video_game
                   INNER JOIN
                   video_game_platform_mycollection ON video_game.Game_Id =      video_game_platform_mycollection.Game_Id
     INNER JOIN
                     platform ON video_game_platform_mycollection.Platform_Id =      platform.Platform_Id
                    INNER JOIN
                   mycollection ON   video_game_platform_mycollection.MyCollection_Id =      mycollect     `enter code here`ion.MyCollection_Id
             where  mycollection.Completeness_Type not like   concat('%',Completenessip,'%');
                END
              $$

                 DELIMITER ;
```

I am calling procedure with

```
       call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('I');   --- **It is working**
        call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('BI');  -- **Not Working**
            call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('BIC');  --**not working**
```

**For the first Example: call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('I');**
I would like to display completeness_type column which does not contain 'I' So, the records in completeenss_type column has to be 'B', 'C', 'BC'

For the second call:
**Expected output: call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('BI');** 
I would like to display completeness_type column which does not contain  'B','I' ,'BI','IC', 'BC', 'BIC'So, the records in completenenss_type column has to be 'c'

**For the Third call:call Get_Info_By_Games_missing_Something('BIC');**
I would like to display completeness_type column which does not contain  'B','I', 'C', 'BI', 'IC','BC', 'BIC' So, the records in completenenss_type column has to be no records

So, could you please tell what is the mistake I am making. I got this query working for rows which does not contain only 'B', 'I' or 'C'. I just want result for rows which does not contain 'BI' or 'B' or 'I' individually

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your exact question, but it seems to be there may be a better way. It's a little unclear what your values correspond to, but one easy way is to have three columns, `B`, `I`, and `C` which could be `BIT` type. You might have success storing it similar to how Unix permissions are stored; such that a file is stored as BIC so a row of type B would be encoded as 100, and IC would read 011. Depending on a couple of factors this may be better than the individual columns, but as an off-the-cuff answer based on what your queries look like, I suspect the discrete columns are going to be easier to code.

Then, of course, to search for a row with BI you'd search for columns `` WHERE `B`=1 AND `I`=1 AND `C`=0 `` and so on with the other searches. This is will scale better and is a better database design than using ENUM fields.